# Unicode Decode Error for shapefile in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, geojson, encoding, unicode

I have Python script for converting shapefiles to Geojson. My code works well if I use some usa data, but when I want to use some other encoding, it gives me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1475, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>   File "C:/Users/name/PycharmProjects/desktopApp/core.py", line 105, in
>   shp2geojson
>       for sr in reader.shapeRecords():
>   File "C:\Python33\lib\shapefile.py", line 553, in shapeRecords
>       for rec in zip(self.shapes(), self.records())]
>   File "C:\Python33\lib\shapefile.py", line 525, in records
>       r = self.__record()   File "C:\Python33\lib\shapefile.py", line 501, in __record
>       value = u(value)   File "C:\Python33\lib\shapefile.py", line 60, in u
>       return v.decode('utf-8')
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position
>   10: invalid continuation byte

How to fix this problem?

```
  import shapefile
  import json

  def shp2geojson():

        filename = askopenfilename()
        reader = shapefile.Reader(filename)
        fields = reader.fields[1:]
        field_names = [field[0] for field in fields]            
        buffer = []

        for sr in reader.shapeRecords():
            atr = dict(zip(field_names, sr.record))
            geom = sr.shape.__geo_interface__
            buffer.append(dict(type="Feature", \
                               geometry=geom, properties=atr))


        geojson = open('shp.json', "w")
        geojson.write(dumps({"type": "FeatureCollection", \
                             "features": buffer}, indent=2) + "\n")
        geojson.close()
```

Comment: At which line of your code do you get that error? If you have special characters in your buffer, the print command will throw this error.

Comment: Nice function. No need for forward slashes there: line continuation is implicit within parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out so I'm posting the answer here:

```
geojson = open('shp.json', "w", encoding='utf-8')
```

Add

> encoding='utf-8'

to this line while creating json file. Works great!

Comment: Great you were able to answer your own question.  It usually takes 2 days on GIS.SE be allowed to accept your own answer, but please do so when available to close the thread.  Thanks!

Comment: More details about the Unicode changes in Python 3 at http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html.